# Payment gate-way implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, payment-gateway, zuora

We are developing a rails application and now i have to integrate ZUORA as a payment gate way .
I never done third party integration so not aware about this but after googling i got some hint like

1- we can give link on our web site and can redirect user to payment gate-way

Now i just want to know that is there any gem or plug-in which can be useful to integrate ZUORA with my app

or how can i proceed and integrate ZUORA.

Is there any one who work with zuora please share their suggestion.

Comment: http://rubygems.org/gems/zuora - google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zuora provides a sample RoR application:

http://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/@api/deki/files/381/Zuora_quickstart_ruby.zip